# TcpClient does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm trying to make a simple program that connects to an irc client.

In another post on code review, I saw this line:

```
 using (var irc = new TcpClient(_server, _port))
```

I have attempted to use this in my application but I get the error

> TcpClient does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

According to the MSDN docs [TcpClient Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/115ytk56(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) it should take `string server, int port` parameters.

:

```
class IRCBot
{
    private readonly string _server;
    private readonly int _port;

    public IRCBot (string server, int port)
    {
        _server = server;
        _port = port;
    }

    public void ChannelConnect()
    {
        do
        {
            try
            {
                using (var irc = new TcpClient(_server, _port))

                // Rest of code
}
```

Comment: Are you using .NET, or .NET Core?  I believe this isn't the way it's done in .NET Core

Comment: I just created a c# console application in VS Code so I guess it would be on the .NET Core framework. Do you have any insight on how it's done in Core?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET Core try this:

```
// Create the client.
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
// Connect to the server.
await client.Connect​Async(​_server, _port);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.-ctor?view=netcore-1.1#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient__ctor